# How to return multiple findObjectsInBackground in a PFTablequery

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to load my PFQueryTableViewController with this query..it keeps coming back blank... I dont think I'm returning the query right.. I don't know how to access the objects from the "secondQuery" that is WITHIN the "AdminQuery"..

thanks in advance!

```
  func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

let getAdminquery = PFQuery(className: "Employee")
getAdminquery.whereKey("companyEmployee", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
getAdminquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

  if error == nil {

    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

      for object in objects {

        let adminFollowingUser = object["companyAdmin"]  as! String

        let secondQuery = PFQuery(className:"PoolAccount")

        secondQuery.whereKey("userId",equalTo:adminFollowingUser)
        secondQuery.findObjects()

      }
    }
  }
}

return getAdminquery //return secondQuery can't be called...
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this code is incomplete or not, but it's a very odd thing to do to define a function inside a closure like that.  But anyway, doesn't look like you're calling that function and it won't be accessible outside the scope of that closure, so the closure itself does nothing.  I can't say for certain whether this will solve all your problems, but if you just get rid of that nested function `queryForTable` and allow the code in its body to execute in the body of the closure you can at least continue debugging.

Answer (score 1):

As Patrick Lynch states, you're defining a function inside a closure. I don't think you need that dispatch_async, since the `PFQueryTableViewController` already does the job for you. `queryForTable()`should not be inside `viewDidLoad` either.

Define which class you want the table to display, is it `PoolAccount`? `PFQueryTableViewController`s queryForTable does only support returning a single query. However, if your classes are related you might be able to do it anyway, with `PFQuery(orQueryWithSubqueries)` and the `query.includeKey()`.

Note:
However, when you do figure out how to get the method to run properly, you're creating `objects.count`queries in the for-loop. If the first query get 200 results, you want to run another 200 queries? That will probably exceed your request limit to Parse.com.

Instead, consider storing all `adminFollowingUser` in an array, and query the PoolAccount with `.whereKey("key", containedIn: YourArray)`, or similar.

Comment: the class i would like it to display is the "Pool Account" Class...but its a little complicated..its like a instragram type set up where if you follow someone you get to see there information...so thats what I'm trying to get out of the first part of the query...im querying for the user that is being followed and then querying that users information...so its querying from 2 different classes.....i updated my code for ya. just not sure how to go about getting the objects out of the subqueried class...im still working on it...if ya have any other ideas let me know thanks!

Comment: Alright, I have done some following things in Parse. 
I created a class called "following" with two pointers, User -> _User and Following -> _User. Then I query.whereKey(User, equalTo: PFUser.currentUser(). So in the result I get all the users that the currentUser is following. Then I do another query from post, maybe Pool Account in your case, where the post (in my case) is posted by any of the users from the first results (I put them in an array and query.whereKey("key", contained in"). Note that I do not use PFQueryTableVC but a regular one, since I need two queries from separate classes.

Comment: awww...i see...thats the problems I've had...i can get them to display on a regular tableview by appending the objects to an array...but my main problem is being able to have a detail view controller with these returned objects...do you have a detail view controller off of your regular tableviews with these pfobjects that you have returned? that is the reason I'm trying to do it on a PFQuerytableview just for the detail view controller aspect...

Comment: Well, yes, I do use selectedRowAtIndexPath for that purpose. Since I'm using an array of PFObjects to create my cells, I can use that prepareForSegue. I'm on mobile now, but I can help you when I get back, tomorrow.

Comment: that will be awesome man! just let me know when your back on maybe we can jump in a chat room and figure this out! thanks mattias!

Comment: No problem, I encountered a lot of problems starting using Parse, happy to help. See you later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84037/discussion-between-mattias-and-steve-derienzo).